# Look code below , how can I get this {"a":1,"b":2} using JSON.sringify?

Tags: javascript

obj is recursive,how can i get rid of it and get this {"a":1,"b":2} using JSON.sringify?

```
var
  obj = {},
  a = 1,
  b = 2;
Object.assign(obj, {
  a, b, obj
});
```

Comment: What? `obj` is recursive because you explicitly assign it into itself; if that's not what you want, **don't do that**. Why not simply `var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };`?

Comment: it's a interview question  and i need use JSON.stringify to get {"a":1,"b":2}

Comment: From which starting point? And if this is an interview question, is asking SO not cheating? They're trying to determine *your* capability, not *mine*.

Comment: in 4.17 , i was asked that question , but i can't figure it out after these days,so i ask. SO i'm not cheating.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 you could do this with [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions).

```js
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = {a, b};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(c, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Before your answer , i assume JSON.stringify() only accept one param.

Comment: i still think, that my proposal is a wrong answer, because you have a circular reference, which does not work with `stringify`. anyway circular references are always a bit strange. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> and i need use JSON.stringify to get {"a":1,"b":2}

You can utilize the `replacer` parameter of [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
var res = JSON.stringify({}, (key, obj) => 
 ["a", "b"].map((v, k) => obj[v] = k + 1) && obj
)
```

Comment: thanks , cool answer , i had spent a afternoon to understand your code , i learn a lot of new things about es6 and json.stringify.